# What does "filetype plugin on" really do?

Tags: filetype

I understand that it loads the `ftplugin.vim` file, but what does it really do? Does it set options (depending on the filetype)?

If I were to include this line at the start of my vimrc

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

and then I set some options after this line (like autoindent, smartindent, etc.), would it mess with them? How can I know which options are affected by a filetype plugin or indent file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is actually a good description in `help filetype`.

Any options that are defined for a filetype will be set with `setlocal`:

```
:setl[ocal] ...     Like ":set" but set only the value local to the
                    current buffer or window.  Not all options have [..]
```

For example `/usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/javascript.vim` defines:

```
setlocal commentstring=//%s
```

Because local options have priority over global ones your `.vimrc` settings might be ignored. In that case you need to create a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` (with the name of the filetype you wish to change) and set your own `setlocal` options in there.

The easiest way to see which options are set is to just open the files for the filetype in `/usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin`, `../indent` and `../syntax`.

Answer (score 5):

It defines autocommands that'll get executed when a file matching a given pattern is opened. These autocommands `source` in turn the filetype plugin**s** associated to the filetype recognized.

In those filetype plugin scripts, you'll be able to find/write anything that you can put in a vim script. The good practice is no never define global things, but exclusively local things. i.e:

- local options with `:setlocal opt=value`
- local mappings with `:[cnivsxot](nore)map <buffer> ...`
- local abbreviations with `:iab-<buffer> ...` & co
- local commands with `:command -b ...`
- local variables with `:let b:var = 42`

Regarding

- menus, you'll have to use plugins that emulate local menus, see Michael Geddes' plugin or [my modernized fork](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/buffermenu.vim) ;
- functions, you can put them in ftplugins, but they are best defined in autoload plugins.

Comment: So there are three kinds of built-in plugin systems: `ftplugin/`, `indent/`, and `autoload/`?

Comment: @job_start there are more: `compiler/` plugins, `syntax/` files, plain `plugin/` files, and a few more like `colorscheme/`. If you `:sp $VIMRUNTIME` you should see how vim organizes _standard_ "plugin" files.

Comment: I just played around(opening) some of them and this is really helpful, thank you :)! By the way, while not related but: could you explain why it's called "runtime"?